# read.table expects 39 columns in .txt file, when there are only 20

Tags: r, txt, file-read

I'm trying to read a .txt file. For some reason I get the following error message:

```
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  line 1 did not have 39 elements
```

I used the following code:

```
FAMA <- read.table("FAMAFrench.txt", header = TRUE)
```

There are only 20 columns of data, none of the rows have gaps. The columns are delimited by spaces.
There are 1166 rows of data

The .txt file looks like this:

```
month  <= 0      Lo 30  Med 40   Hi 30   Lo 20   Qnt 2   Qnt 3   Qnt 4   Hi 20   Lo 10   Dec 2   Dec 3   Dec 4   Dec 5   Dec 6   Dec 7   Dec 8   Dec 9   Hi 10
192607  -99.99    0.14    1.54    3.42    0.37    0.48    1.68    1.41    3.67   -0.12    0.52   -0.05    0.82    1.39    1.89    1.62    1.29    3.53    3.71
192608  -99.99    3.19    2.73    2.91    2.21    3.58    3.70    1.50    3.07    1.13    2.55    4.00    3.32    2.76    4.41    1.54    1.49    0.61    3.79
192609  -99.99   -1.73   -0.88    0.80   -1.39   -1.25    0.07   -0.23    0.81    0.59   -2.00   -2.01   -0.77   -0.01    0.13   -1.93    0.74   -0.77    1.25
192610  -99.99   -2.94   -3.26   -2.79   -2.56   -3.99   -2.65   -3.36   -2.74   -4.29   -2.01   -3.25   -4.45   -3.02   -2.39   -3.55   -3.26   -3.36   -2.56
192611  -99.99   -0.38    3.73    2.74   -0.95    3.03    3.50    3.25    2.71   -3.28   -0.23    0.08    4.90    3.56    3.45    3.60    3.05    3.86    2.40
192612  -99.99    4.15    1.66    3.04    2.45    3.47    1.37    2.81    3.00   -2.49    3.93    5.60    2.22    1.33    1.40    1.81    3.37    3.11    2.97
```

Comment: Typical example of invalid column names with spaces. E.g. `Lo 30`  will be split in two columns due to the space in between. You can quote these `"Lo 30"` and they're recognized as one string.

Answer (score 2):

The columns are separated by more than one space. `read.table` can only use one byte, though. What you can do is to skip the first row (i.e. the header), and read it in separately using `readLines`. Then you can `strsplit` it at `'\\s{2,}'` (two or more spaces) and `setNames` with it.

```
read.table('file.txt', skip=1) |>
  setNames(el(strsplit(readLines('file.txt', 1), '\\s{2,}')))
#    month   <= 0 Lo 30 Med 40 Hi 30 Lo 20 Qnt 2 Qnt 3 Qnt 4 Hi 20 Lo 10 Dec 2 Dec 3 Dec 4 Dec 5 Dec 6 Dec 7 Dec 8 Dec 9 Hi 10
# 1 192607 -99.99  0.14   1.54  3.42  0.37  0.48  1.68  1.41  3.67 -0.12  0.52 -0.05  0.82  1.39  1.89  1.62  1.29  3.53  3.71
# 2 192608 -99.99  3.19   2.73  2.91  2.21  3.58  3.70  1.50  3.07  1.13  2.55  4.00  3.32  2.76  4.41  1.54  1.49  0.61  3.79
# 3 192609 -99.99 -1.73  -0.88  0.80 -1.39 -1.25  0.07 -0.23  0.81  0.59 -2.00 -2.01 -0.77 -0.01  0.13 -1.93  0.74 -0.77  1.25
# 4 192610 -99.99 -2.94  -3.26 -2.79 -2.56 -3.99 -2.65 -3.36 -2.74 -4.29 -2.01 -3.25 -4.45 -3.02 -2.39 -3.55 -3.26 -3.36 -2.56
# 5 192611 -99.99 -0.38   3.73  2.74 -0.95  3.03  3.50  3.25  2.71 -3.28 -0.23  0.08  4.90  3.56  3.45  3.60  3.05  3.86  2.40
# 6 192612 -99.99  4.15   1.66  3.04  2.45  3.47  1.37  2.81  3.00 -2.49  3.93  5.60  2.22  1.33  1.40  1.81  3.37  3.11  2.97
```